# C++ Callbacks with objective-C, an application to RtMidi

Tags: objective-c, callback

I've read several of the previous discussion about the subject but since I'm relatively new to Objective-C, I don't really understand them. (Blocks, selectors, and delegate are very new to me).

Here is the situation:
I'm using those abstract class RtMidi that are written in c++

```
void MidiInApi :: setCallback( RtMidiIn::RtMidiCallback callback, void *userData )
{
  if ( inputData_.usingCallback ) {
    errorString_ = "MidiInApi::setCallback: a callback function is already set!";
    RtMidi::error( RtError::WARNING, errorString_ );
    return;
  }

  if ( !callback ) {
    errorString_ = "RtMidiIn::setCallback: callback function value is invalid!";
    RtMidi::error( RtError::WARNING, errorString_ );
    return;
}

inputData_.userCallback = (void *) callback;
inputData_.userData = userData;
inputData_.usingCallback = true;
}
```

I also have a class that Reciever that implements that callback (rtMidiCallback).
And at some point in my main file I need to write something like this

```
        midiIn->setCallback(rtMidiCallback);
```

This Would be in a c++ context but in Objective-C I have no idea how to do it.

If you have any ideas, pointers I would be glad to discuss about it with you. Thank you very much

Best,

greg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to have C++ and Objective-C within the same project and even within the same file (Objective-C++ with file extension .mm).  If the code you're using is designed for a C++ callback, it may be easier to provide that and communicate between different object types outside of that mechanism.

---

```
//  CPPClass.h

#ifndef CPPClass_h
#define CPPClass_h

class CPPClass {
private:
    id m_ocObject;

public:
    CPPClass(id ocObject);
    virtual ~CPPClass();

    void verifyCPP();

};

#endif
```

---

```
//  OCClass.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class CPPClass;

@interface OCClass : NSObject {
    CPPClass *cppObject;
}

- (void)ocCallback;
- (void)verifyOC;

@end
```

---

```
//  OCClass.mm

#import "OCClass.h"
#import "CPPClass.h"

#include <iostream>

@implementation OCClass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        cppObject = new CPPClass(self);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete cppObject;
}

- (void)ocCallback {
    NSLog(@"Objective-C called from C++");
}

- (void)verifyOC {
    NSLog(@"Objective-C called from Objective-C");
    cppObject->verifyCPP();
}

@end

CPPClass::CPPClass(id ocObject) : m_ocObject(ocObject)
{}

CPPClass::~CPPClass() {}

void CPPClass::verifyCPP() {
    std::cout << "C++ called from Objective-C" << std::endl;
    [m_ocObject ocCallback];
}
```

To activate this, some other .mm file would have:

```
#import "OCClass.h"
...
OCClass *test = [[OCClass alloc] init];
[test verifyOC];
```

Comment: Thannk you Phillip for your answer. That's what I'm trying. But the function I callback creates a struct that I would like to send to other objective-c class. I dont know how to communicate that information.

Comment: It's a bit verbose, but I've added a basic sample of 2-way calling between Objective-C and C++ to the answer; maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explaination is very handy !

Comment: I know we are supposed to avoid "thanks!" but seriously this was killing me for over 20 hours and finally read this and just tried implementing it and it worked perfectly. amazing. THANKS!!!!