# Linking existing C++ framework to an Objective-C + Cocoa application

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, multiplatform

I've developed a working framework for windows at school, which has all the classes and methods needed for a window to work. Here's an example of part of few classes, I'm not gonna paste all the code here tho.

Widget.h (base class)

```
class Widget {
    public:
        Widget(...);
        ...
        virtual std::string getLabel() const;
        virtual void setLabel(const std::string label);
        ...
    private:
        std::string m_label;
        Widget* m_parent;
        Measure m_position; // struct: int x, int y
        Measure m_size;
};
```

Button.h

```
class Button : public Widget {
    public:
        Button(...);
        ...
        virtual void setTarget(Widget* target);
        ...
    private:
        Widget* m_target;
};
```

LineEdit.h

```
class LineEdit : public Widget {
    public:
        LineEdit(...);
        ...
        virtual void setMaximumLenght(int lenght);
        ...
    private:
        int m_maximumLength;
};
```

And so on... These are all just header files, and I have implemented methods etc. inside the corresponding `.cpp` file.

My homework for this period is to implement them for Mac's OS-X in Objective-C and Cocoa, so the headers work in both OS-X and Windows. I can do rest myself, but I would like to know how to use these header files in the OS-X, and therefore just rewrite the implementations into a `.m` file, instead of `.cpp`. Any ideas? I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: I sene some confusion in your question as iOS != Mac, and you seem to be mixing the two indiscriminately.

Comment: Upsie, fixed it to osx. Thanks for the note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine .cpp files and .m files in the same project, which means that if your implementation doesn't have any Windows-specific code you can add it to the project and compile it.  There is also the concept of *Objective-C++*.  With it, you can write code in `.mm` files using both C++ and Objective-C and make calls between them.

On the other hand, if you really need to implement everything in Objective-C, you'll need to rewrite the headers to define Objective-C classes (not C++ ones) as well as rewriting the implementation.

Comment: So basically I can create a `LineEdit.mm`-file which includes the header, and inside the file say `void LineEdit::setMaximumLength(int length) { <cocoa/objective-c code here> }`, and it will work?

Comment: **Very** basically, yes.  :)  Here's a link to a question where I answered with what is probably the simplest Objective-C++ code possible.  Maybe it will help with the concept.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236476/c-callbacks-with-objective-c-an-application-to-rtmidi/13236838#13236838  The `verifyCPP` function is about what you're suggesting.

Comment: Appears to be much easier than I thought! Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: The one problem you can hit is header conflicts - especially if the C++ code uses Boost or some other library with a huge collection of headers that might clash with Cocoa.h. In that case what you can do is make another C++ (.mm) class of your own that is a simple proxy that needs no complex includes in it's .h file and then forwards calls to the underlying C++ (.c++) object itself.