# Calling Objective-C methods from CPP code

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am very new to Objective-C.
I wan to call Objective-C methods from a C++ class defined in separate .cpp file.

I have used the same mechanism described in this question's answer by `dreamlax` (not the PIMPL one)
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method`

But i am stuck at point how to call function `int MyCPPClass::someMethod (void *objectiveCObject, void *aParameter);` from CPP class with the parameters `objectiveCObject`.

Also can some one please explain how to call a C++ class functions from Objective-C Code with an Example.

Comment: I once wrote a very simple example of this as a response to someone's question.  Maybe it will give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236476/c-callbacks-with-objective-c-an-application-to-rtmidi/13236838#13236838

Comment: Thanks for the example, in your 'OCClass.mm' file at the end you have added C++ class implementation. can we move this implementation to separate C++ file? or it should be in that file only.

Comment: It needs to be in a .mm file because it uses Objective-C code as part of that implementation.  I suppose it could be moved into its own file but my habit with O-C++ has been to connect the languages via one pair of classes and implement them together so that I have only one place to look for that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use Objective-C++ in the file that does the call. To do so from Xcode, rename the file from `Whatever.m` to `Whatever.mm`. Then you can mix calls.